# Find works fine in command line, but won't work in script

Tags: linux, bash, find, regular-expression

I am trying to write a script on a Debian Jessie host.

I am having an issue with trying to run the following command (with a twist) in a script:

```
find ~/* -path ~/FileSniper* \
-prune -o \
-type f \( -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.sh" -or -name "*.mp3" \) \
! -name '*.txt' -printf "%f\n"
```

What I am trying to do in the script is make the  user have to type in the file formats he/she wants to search for, after that, I pipe this to `sed`, which will make sure it obtains the right format:

```
 echo "Input the formats like this: \"mp3,mp4,exe,sh\""
        read -p "input:" formats
        formattedformats=`echo "-name \"*.""$formats""\"" | sed 's/,/" -o -name "*./g'`
        find_parameters=(\(formattedformats\))
```

Here the `$find_parameters` will contain something like:

```
-name "*.mp3" -o -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.sh"
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with this line:

```
find ~/* -path ~/FileSniper* -prune -o -type f  "${find_parameters[@]}" ! -name "*.txt" -printf "%f\n" > foundfiles.txt
```

I have researched what I could, but still haven't been able to figure out what is wrong. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: If 'users' are running this script, -path ~/FileSniper* refers to their home directory. Also, try putting the full path to find instead of find like: /usr/bin/find also you are echoing to a file without putting the full path to the file. Try fixing all the relative path issues and possible $PATH issues and see if that fixes it. Once you have done these fixes, and if it still doesn't work, it might be easier to debug it.

Comment: is there a reason for `~/*` ? are you trying to exclude hidden `.` directories?  you could do `find ~ -not -path '*/.*' ...` instead.

Comment: i would also advise taking the input as command-line arguments rather than prompting and reading stdin - that way it's easier to re-use your script from other scripts just by calling it as, e.g., `scriptname.sh mp3 mp4 exe sh`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that reads the file extensions from the command line (rather than from stdin) and uses them to build a regular expression to use with `find`'s `-iregex` option.

It excludes hidden `.` directories and `~/FileSniper*` as in your original example.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

regexp=''

for ext in "$@" ; do
    [ -n "$regexp" ] && regexp="$regexp\|"
    regexp="$regexp.*\.$ext$"
done

find ~ -not -path '*/.*' -not -path '*/FileSniper*' -type f \
    -iregex "$regexp" > foundfiles.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If your script is a `#!/bin/sh` type or is otherwise just `.sh` then it would explain why your `${find_parameters[@]}` doesn't work on a Debian system which uses a default `dash` shell interpreter that doesn't implement the `${array[@]}` type name extension.

I can also see how your `-path ~/FileSniper*` argument might come off with unwanted results - and the same goes for `~/*` for that matter. As written those are shell expansions - not `find` expansions. The `find [ ...paths... ]` operands never expand and so `~/*` - if that's really what you want - is as correct as it might be, but `-path ~/FileSniper*` is expanded to whatever the results might be by the parent shell *before* it is used as a pattern by `find`. And so if it doesn't match a `~/` path it is a moot point because `*` will remain as is anyway, but if it *does* then it no longer works as the pattern you intend.

You should quote it, probably: `find ... -path ~/FileSniper\*` unless you mean to look for a literal `~` tilde, in which case you should quote that, too.